# Read A Multidimesion String Array From File

Tags: python, arrays, file

I want to read a multidimensional list of string values which contain special character from a file(.txt or .out).
Then i have to read a first value of first row and compare with second value of same row.

Like:

```
[
        ["this","why this7656^"]
        ["@this","whAy @this code"],
        ["is ", "this@@#@# code is complex"],
        ["@#@#", "Test@#@#his Test"]
    ]
```

My Question is How to extract these value.
Value must be read in this format - <"this">

I tried to split/join but couldn't get exact one string (Either it's giving whole line or splitting it in character by character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample string looks like [JSON](http://json.org/).

Use the Python [JSON Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to decode it:

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    data = json.loads(content)
```

Comment: Yes It look like JSON but i need to know for text file and then i will move to _JSON_ and JSON is giveing result like this


    [[u'this', u'why this7656^'], [u'@this', u'whAy @this code'], [u'is ', u'this@@#@# code is complex'], [u'@#@#', u'Test@#@#his Test']]

Comment: how to do it with python < 2.5

Comment: Whats wrong with the result in your first comment? It seems correct to me. For python 2.4 install simplejson 2.1.0: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/2.1.0

Comment: [Any Answer to this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/15872359/import-json-in-staf-stax)

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice - using 'eval' - but it is the simplest way to solve your issue. You only **must** guarantee that statement you will evaluating is safe and correct Python's code. Try this:

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    data = eval(content)
    print ['<%s>' % x[0] for x in l]
```

After retrieving Python collection, I hope it will not a problem to extract required data items for you.

**UPD:** Another way - use regex like '["(.*?)"' - it will match any string which started with "[", following by double-quote char without separator. After that I specified non-greedy pattern and closed expression with another double-quote symbol. not sure it will be more preferable approach, but it takes place.

Comment: 'code'
with open("D:\\ReadData.txt", "r") as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    data = eval(content)
    print data


Traceback (most recent call last):
data = eval(content)
 File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: It looks like you forget comma after `["this","why this7656^"]`. Is that code provided by 3rd party service - without comma?

Comment: Sorry My Mistake (It Worked)

Comment: I'm not able to extract the value 
May i have some more hints.

Comment: Why doesn't `eval()` reads `\n` from file ?? Any explanation ??

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import ast
>>> text = '''[
        ["this", "why this7656^"],
        ["@this", "whAy @this code"],
        ["is ", "this@@#@# code is complex"],
        ["@#@#", "Test@#@#his Test"]
    ]'''
>>> ast.literal_eval(text)
[['this', 'why this7656^'], ['@this', 'whAy @this code'], ['is ', 'this@@#@# code is complex'], ['@#@#', 'Test@#@#his Test']]
```

Comment: This will also give the same result??
`import string`
`with open("D:\\ReadData.txt") as f:`
`lines = f.readline()`
`print line`